# How to absorb ingredients through topical application

Tags: nutrition, health

What is the best way to obtain the natural ingredients of a natural plant and get them into my system?

We get protein by eating meat, eggs, etc . This way our body fills with protein so it can build muscle while we are working.

This is food intake by mouth.

The other way is not to eat the protein but to place it in the surface of our body.
If we have a plant(example broccoli, cauliflower, rosemary, etc) and we want all the good ingredients to be stored (not only by intake by eating)

1. I take a glass or bowl, I put some of the broccoli or something similar inside it. I leave it inside for 1 day. Does the water have all the nutrients?
2. When I finish a workout, if I apply this water on the surface of my legs or biceps, etc, will it store the nutrients even more?

I have heard that there is the way to do, e.g., the broccoli in the kitchen, but when you open the temperature the ingredients will be lost.

Comment: Short answer is that, as far as I can tell, topical application of nutrients/supplements can be useful for skin health, but has nothing to do with anything internal without the additional of certain chemicals that can cause drugs to get into our systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment, the short answer is that this does not work. [The military are working on it, and there are companies advertising patches](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/can-you-absorb-nutrients-through-your-skin/), but the current state of the art seems to indicate that most nutrients, including protein, will not permeate the skin.

> In order to be absorbed through your skin and into your bloodstream, a compound needs to have at least two things going for it. It needs to be lipophilic, or fat-soluble. And it needs to be very, very small. A lot of the compounds found in commercially-marketed transdermal patches are neither.
>
> Of course, there are ways to get around these limitations. You can break a large molecule down into nanoparticles, or encase it in a substance that diffuses more easily into the lipid layer of the skin. You can use tiny little needles to poke tiny little holes in the skin, which allows the substance to penetrate into the deeper tissues. You can use chemicals to alter the surface of the skin and make it more porous. You can even use electrical stimulation to open the pores, or a technique known as microdialysis.

**TL;DR, eat your broccoli instead of slathering it on your skin**

As a small codicil, there are some things that are good for your *skin* when slathered on, in much the same way that painting sealant on your deck will help its surface without changing anything about the health of the board internals.

Comment: As I understand ,Dear Sean ,correct me if I am wrong. From what I got ,is if I did the way I discribed ,will make my skin get some nutritients etc UP to my skin which is good for my skin ,  but will not go under my skin (example for grow muscle). Is this right?

Comment: That is correct. Without measures like drugs to make the skin more permeable, micro-punctures, nanoparticalization, etc, those sorts of vitamins and proteins can't get through the skin, was has evolved to protect us from such contamination.

Comment: Thank you Dear Sean Duggan

Comment: @e.p. The skin is made of cells, which have membranes. Membranes that are basically there to keep things out (and in). They possess very few mechanisms to transport anything bigger than water molecules through and most of these mechanisms are extremely selective in what they transport.